# Rotating Sprite around Y-Axis (2D)

Tags: 2d, iphone, sprites, rotation

I'm going to be creating a game soon, and part of it involves spinning sprites. The sprites will be spinning around the Y-Axis (imagine a spinning plate on top of a stick, where the stick stands up vertically.

The main way I've thought of is to have a series of sprites for various rotation values that I blur between as the 'plate' rotates (the sprite is more complex than a plate, though).

The game will be for iPhone, but I'm open to using any 2D gave development library for it.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Benlitz sorry if that wasn't clear, I was wondering if there is an 'accepted' way of doing this or if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer will help if you want to use a textured quad, but not if you want to use a series of pre-rotated sprites.

First, determine the pivot point of your sprite. If your sprite is `32x32` and you want to spin the sprite around its center, then its pivot point will be `(16, 16)`. Simple.

```
const tb::Vec2& pivot = m_Sprite->GetPivot();
const tb::Vec2& dim = m_Sprite->GetDimensions();
```

Then, create a 2D matrix. In your case, you want:

```
tb::Mat3x3 transform;
transform.Identity();
transform.AddRotation(angle);
transform.AddTranslation(m_Position);
```

2D matrices are really easy. Here's what the final matrix looks like from the inside:

```
float rads = tb::Math::DegToRad(m_Rotation);

values[X1] = -tb::Math::Sin(rads); 
values[Y1] =  tb::Math::Cos(rads);
values[WX] =  0.f;

values[X2] =  tb::Math::Cos(rads); 
values[Y2] =  tb::Math::Sin(rads);
values[WY] =  0.f;

values[TX] =  m_Position.x;
values[TY] =  m_Position.y;
values[CZ] =  1.f;
```

Construct four corner points in object space. That sounds difficult, but it looks like this:

```
tb::Vec2 pos_ul = tb::Vec2(m_Position.x - pivot.x,         m_Position.y - pivot.y        );
tb::Vec2 pos_ur = tb::Vec2(m_Position.x - pivot.x + dim.x, m_Position.y - pivot.y        );
tb::Vec2 pos_ll = tb::Vec2(m_Position.x - pivot.x        , m_Position.y - pivot.y + dim.y);
tb::Vec2 pos_lr = tb::Vec2(m_Position.x - pivot.x + dim.x, m_Position.y - pivot.y + dim.y);
```

Using your matrix, you can transform those corner points:

```
pos_ul = transform * pos_ul;
pos_ur = transform * pos_ur;
pos_ll = transform * pos_ll;
pos_lr = transform * pos_lr;
```

And now you can use those coordinates for a textured quad.

For future reference:

- Any transformation can be done with a matrix.
- Try getting the end result you want without a matrix first and then try to turn it into a single matrix.
- Math is your friend!

Comment: I love the fact that my answer got downvoted by the community, but accepted by the OP. XD

Answer (score 1):

I use rotsprite - it was designed for this purpose.

Comment: What is rotsprite? Are you referring to a utility or a class in some library? A link would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way of rotating graphics on iOS is to add a translucent border to the image to have antialiased borders. There are many questions like these on SO, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285354/line-is-not-smooth-on-layer-border-when-its-rotated, which includes a link to http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/ (most answers do).